# Deadlock: will order of resource return have any potential issue?

Tags: deadlock

```
// down = acquire the resource
// up = release the resource

typedef int semaphore;
  semaphore resource_1;
  semaphore resource_2;


 void process_A(void) {
    down(&resource_1);
    down(&resource_2);
    use_both_resources();
    up(&resource_2);
    up(&resource_1);
 }
```

If the resource return in the same order as it acquired, i.e,

```
 void process_A(void) {
    down(&resource_1);
    down(&resource_2);
    use_both_resources();
    up(&resource_1);
    up(&resource_2);
 }
```

Would that cause any potential problem.
Thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is if you are taking the locks in the same order in different threads or not.

The order of release has no effect; there's nothing stopping the program from releasing the second lock after the first one has been released, (unless you're taking new locks in between, but then you're back at the first case; taking the locks in the correct order.)

If you have two functions that try to take the same two locks, in different orders, they could grab one lock each, and wait forever for the other one to release their lock. Example code:

```
down(first_lock)
down(second_lock)
```

running concurrently with

```
down(second_lock)
down(first_lock)
```

they could both take their first lock before any of them take their second lock, and then they'll deadlock.

Comment: Order of release has no effect in this specific process. We don't know what is the order in the competing threads.

Comment: Okey, if you depend on locks being released in the correct order so that you don't grab them in the wrong order, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I knew what the problem would be if there's a competing process. I was just confused by if that would make any difference in just single thread code.

Comment: That's not what you asked :) In single threaded code, the only way you could deadlock is if you try to grab the same lock twice, without releasing it between.

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of the things needed for a deadlock to occour.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions

Comment: @FilipHaglund Actually, whether or not acquiring the lock twice will result in a deadlock, depends on the type of locking mechanism used. E.g., reentrant mutexes allow such behavior.